# Where can I find Internet Explorer v6.0.2800.1106CO?

Tags: download, internet-explorer-6

Does anyone know where I can download Internet Explorer **v6.0.2800.1106CO** from?

I need this specific version - even **v6.0.2800.1106** (note missing CO) is not good enough.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Care to explain why?

Comment: My client is having problems with my app working on that particular IE6 version. There's no way I can talk him into updating his browser nor can he let me work on his computer for security concerns.

Comment: It sounds like your client might just be a bit unreasonable. One solution: look up a vulnerability that only affects that version of IE. Then get him to visit a site with that vulnerability. When his system gets hosed, offer to fix it for him, and in the process, install a newer version of IE. 

Ok, I'm kidding there. But really, if he has "security concerns" he shouldn't be running an outdated browser full of security vulnerabilities... have you tired pointing out that to him?

Comment: It's a very specific client to be honest. I don't know the exact reasons behind theirs sticking to IE6. It's not like a single workstation with IE6 installed. They have more than a hundred workstations with that exact IE6 so I really need to get hold of that particular version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.hpcfactor.com/downloads/msie/ie60sp1/

Comment: It's 6.0.2800.1106, isn't it? I need 6.0.2800.1106CO.

Comment: Internet Explorer v6.0.2800.1106CO is the same as v6.0.2800.1106.

The *CO* suffix just means that the Internet Explorer Administration Kit (IEAK) was used to prepare the installation, and specifically refers to it being provided by a 'Corporate Administrator'.